# How to uninstall all versions of hadoop completely from the system?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, ubuntu-14.04

I had installed CDH5 with Mvr1 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS (single node) in pseudo-distributed mode using this tutorial
http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_qs_mrv1_pseudo.html

I used the command

```
sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo
```

to install the package in pseduo distributed mode.

I then tried to uninstall it and migrate to YARN (MvR2). But in doing so, my datanode fails to start up every time. I removed Mvr1 and installed YARN using this tutorial:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_qs_yarn_pseudo.html.

I used the command

```
sudo apt-get remove hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-*
```

to uninstall Mvr1

and

```
sudo apt-get install hadoop-conf-pseudo
```

to install YARN.

Can you suggest me how to remove all versions of hadoop completely from my system and verify that no file remains before I do a fresh installation?

Answer (score 0):

Do a:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep hadoop
```

to see what packages are installed and then go through the list running:

```
sudo apt-get remove
```

on anything that pops up.  That should remove hadoop completely from your system.